# Get all nouns to an array set using core NLP

Tags: java, arrays, loops, set, stanford-nlp

I'm a beginner to NLP tools. I need to get all the nouns from below code to an array. How can I do this ?

```
public String s = "I like java and python";

public static Set<String> nounPhrases = new HashSet<>();

public void me() {

    Document doc = new Document(" " + s);
    for (Sentence sent : doc.sentences()) {

        System.out.println("The parse of the sentence '" + sent + "' is " + sent.parse());



    }
```

This code gives me the below output.

```
The parse of the sentence 'I like java and python' is (ROOT (S (NP (PRP I)) (VP (VBP like) (NP (NN java) (CC and) (NN python)))))
```

I need all

> NN

to my array set nounPhrases . How can I do this ?

Comment: I'm using Stanford simple core NLP library [link](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/simple.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\(NN\\s+(\\w+)\\)");
Matcher m = pat.matcher(sent.parse().toString());
while (m.find())
    nounPhrase.add(m.group(1));
System.out.println(nounPhrase);
```

result:

```
[python, java]
```